# Mixing lock-less and lock-full thread synchronization with atomic TestAndSet in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, atomic, test-and-set

I have a consumer thread that must read from a buffer **without locking**. It is fine if the operation must be skipped because a producer thread is writing to the buffer. So, the most appropriate choice seems to me to be an **atomic TestAndSet** on some flag.

Now, those aforementioned producer threads must respect this flag as well, because they can't start writing to the buffer while the consumer is reading from it. I could solve this using atomic_flag::test_and_set like the following code:

```
while (flag.test_and_set()) 
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

...but **writing my own spin lock seems less than ideal**. I would rather have my thread sleep until it is woken as a result of the flag being cleared. Something like:

```
flag.enter();
```

**TLDR:** How best to synchronize two threads where one can lock and the other can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `std::mutex`.

The readers can use [`try_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock) to avoid blocking.

The writers (producers) can use the blocking `lock` function as usual.

Of course, to avoid leaking a lock, use [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock).  Readers should pass `std::try_to_lock` as the second argument.  You should then check [`owns_lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/owns_lock) to see whether the data can be safely read or a write was in progress.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping existed -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix and match synchronization methods- both sides must agree. It seems to me that what you really want is to try to acquire the lock and then if it fails, skip. You can use [try_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock) on a regular `std::mutex` to achieve this.

Lockless is impossible if you want the producer to block when the reader is reading.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want -- if I can't grab the lock, go down some alternate branch.